# div not consistently positioned on all desktops

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to CSS/HTML so apologies for the crass coding. I'm having trouble having [my website](https://stingyapples.tumblr.com/) stay consistent on different desktops. On mine it looks exactly as I'd like it to --> [X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U84Z7.jpg). However on my friends' desktops the word "Catitude" is shifted way past the top and cropped.

I have a div containing the head .

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee 
Shade'rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" media="screen" />

[CSS]

#parent {
  position: absolute center; 
  background-color: #FFE1E9; 
  height: 690px;
  width: 1368px;
  margin: auto; 
  border-style:  double;
  border-color: #B8BEFF;
  border-width: 20px; 
}

.text {
  position: relative; 
  top: -150px; 
  left: 166.4px;
  width: 1035px; 
  height: 141px; 
  font-family: "Bungee Shade"; 
  font-size: 150px; 
  color: #B8BEFF;
}

[HTML]

<div id="parent">

<h1 class = "text">CATTITUDE</h1>

<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ttpth8c.png" usemap="#image-map" IMG STYLE = "position:relative; top:-360px" >
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using  px ie ;

```
top: 1035px; 
left: 141px;
```

use percentage % :

```
top: 25%; 
left: 10%;
```

based on your requirments

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I have tried it, however I'm running into the same problem, and it looks even more off on my laptop:

.text {
 position: relative; 
 top: -10%; 
 left: 11.5%;
        width: 1035px; 
 height: 141px; 
 
 font-family: "Bungee Shade"; 
 font-size: 150px; 
 color: #B8BEFF;}

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you dont **automatically center** for your text!

Therefore your layout will be displayed differently on differnet displays as the resolution may vary.

Try this code for your text element:

```
.text {
position: relative; 
top: -150px; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 1035px; 
height: 141px; 
font-family: "Bungee Shade"; 
font-size: 150px; 
color: #B8BEFF;
}
```